Sum Over Partition duplicate rows
My query to show transaction and receipt amounts by transaction are duplicating the transaction amounts when multiple receipts are applied to it.
I'm using select distinct and the sum over partition since a transaction might have multiple lines, and I only want to report the total transaction amount here.
select distinct 
    sum (rctl.revenue_amount) over (partition by rcta.trx_number) as "TRX Ammount",
    acra.receipt_number as "Receipt Number"
from
    apps.ra_customer_trx_all rcta,
    apps.ra_customer_trx_lines_all rctl,
    apps.ar_receivable_applications_all araa,
    apps.ar_cash_receipts_all acra
    
where
    rcta.customer_trx_id = rctl.customer_trx_id
    and rcta.trx_number = '12345'
    and rcta.customer_trx_id = araa.applied_customer_trx_id
    and araa.cash_receipt_id = acra.cash_receipt_id

When running the query for just the rcta and rctl tables, I get the expected value.



TRX Amount




5



When adding in the araa and acra receipt tables, the value is triple, since the transaction here has three receipts applied to it; I know I'll get three rows with the same amount, but I want the amount to actually be correct.



TRX Amount
Receipt Number




15



15
Receipt2


15
Receipt3



I feel like this is probably a basic question, please excuse me as I'm still new to SQL.  From reviewing other threads it looks like it involves having a "From (select distinct" coding but I'm not sure how to do this when joining tables.
Thanks!

You haven't shared any sample input data which makes this difficult to test but:

you probably want to aggregate first and then join after the aggregation; and
you probably don't want to use an analytic function to perform the SUM and then use DISTINCT to get rid of duplicates but want to use SUM and GROUP BY.

You are joining on rcta.customer_trx_id = araa.applied_customer_trx_id so in the rcta table you want to GROUP BY rcta.customer_trx_id (and if you can have multiple transactions then also include the rcta.trx_number in the GROUP BY clause).
Something like this:
SELECT r.trx_amount AS "TRX Ammount",
       -- r.trx_number AS "TRX Number",
       acra.receipt_number AS "Receipt Number"
FROM   ( SELECT rcta.trx_number,
                rcta.customer_trx_id,
                SUM(rctl.revenue_amount) AS trx_amount
         FROM   apps.ra_customer_trx_all rcta
                INNER JOIN apps.ra_customer_trx_lines_all rctl
                ON rcta.customer_trx_id = rctl.customer_trx_id
         WHERE  rcta.trx_number = '12345'
         GROUP BY
                rcta.customer_trx_id,
                rcta.trx_number
       ) r
       INNER JOIN apps.ar_receivable_applications_all araa
       ON r.customer_trx_id = araa.applied_customer_trx_id
       INNER JOIN apps.ar_cash_receipts_all acra
       ON araa.cash_receipt_id = acra.cash_receipt_id


If you do want to use an analytic function then use:
SELECT r.trx_amount AS "TRX Ammount",
       -- r.trx_number AS "TRX Number",
       acra.receipt_number AS "Receipt Number"
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT
                rcta.customer_trx_id,
                rcta.trx_number,
                SUM(rctl.revenue_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY rcta.trx_number) AS trx_amount
         FROM   apps.ra_customer_trx_all rcta
                INNER JOIN apps.ra_customer_trx_lines_all rctl
                ON rcta.customer_trx_id = rctl.customer_trx_id
         WHERE  rcta.trx_number = '12345'
       ) r
       INNER JOIN apps.ar_receivable_applications_all araa
       ON r.customer_trx_id = araa.applied_customer_trx_id
       INNER JOIN apps.ar_cash_receipts_all acra
       ON araa.cash_receipt_id = acra.cash_receipt_id

This will get the correct total for the rcta/rctl tables and then, after calculating the aggregation, you can join to the other tables.
You want to use DISTINCT inside the sub-query to remove the duplicates from the analytic query's aggregation and do not remove duplicates if there are multiple entries in the araa/acra tables (which would be removed if the DISTINCT was in the outer query).
(If you want to get the output for multiple rcta.trx_number then comment out the WHERE filter and uncomment the line in the outer SELECT clause.)

Thanks!  This code is exactly what I needed.
